# Upgrade JAX-RS to 2.0 in Apache TomEE

Tags: jax-rs, cxf, apache-tomee

Currently, Apache TomEE is Java EE 6 compatible and provides only JAX-RS 1.1 specification.

Is there a way to upgrade CXF and use JAX-RS 2.0 to provide REST services?

Comment: Are you using Maven?

Comment: Yes
I would like to know if it's well supported during build and at runtime

Answer (score 1):

there is no way until you fork tomee 7.x openejb-cxf-rs. Upgrading libraries (cxf) is not enough to get a JAXRS 2 server (you will miss @Suspended support and some other parts for instance). It can however be enough to get client API.